# Radio Input disappear on page reload (enum, foreach, default checked, remember answer on page reload)

Tags: php, javascript, html

I might be on the wrong path (tiredness..) for the moment but i have passed 4 hours or something similar to debug my code. I have a form that is auto submitted when I click on a radio button, once clicked the next form appear and let me input the customer information. But when the page reload for displaying the other form, my variable $CustomerType is set and correct and, when i complete the input form (the second one) the php check if everything in it seems correct and it does, but it says my variable $CustomerType is missing then reload the page and ask me again to set the type.

I can't paste all my code out here (~300 lines) but here is the core :

```
<?php $_POST['CustomerType']="SOMEONE"; ?> // Ok so this was the trick, it solved the main bug but it now fix my choice to SOMEONE only. Can't change to another type
<form method="post" action="<?php echo escaped_html($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'URL');?>">
<?php
        $array=show_enum("customer", "CustomerType");
        $checked="";
        foreach($array as $CustomerType) 
        {
            $checked="";                            
            if(isset($_POST['CustomerType'])) 
            {
               if($_POST['CustomerType']==$CustomerType) $checked="checked";
            }
            echo "<input type='radio' name='CustomerType' value=".$CustomerType." ".$checked." onClick='this.form.submit()'>".$CustomerType."</input>";
        }
?> </form>
```

**EDIT** Ok there is some news : by modifying the top who was : `<?php $_POST['CustomerType']="SOMEONE"; ?>`

**TO**

```
if(!isset($_POST['CustomerType'])) $_POST['CustomerType']="SOMEONE";
```

It seems to solve the second problem of the form, which couldn't let me change the type (auto-rollback to SOMEONE). But now, on form submit my choices are always rolling back to [CustomerType] => SOMEONE instead of SOMEBODY (and i checked SOMEBODY).

It means that i can't hold the value $_POST['CustomerType'] on page reload for submitting.

**For example :** This one which seems identical except that it's submitted with "save" button instead of onsubmit is working fine.

```
$array=show_enum("customer", "Language");
foreach($array as $Language) 
{
    $checked="";                            
        if(isset($_POST['Language'])) 
    {
         if($_POST['Language']==$Language) $checked="checked";                      
    }
    else if($Language=="FR") $checked="checked";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='Language' value=".$Language." ".$checked." />";
    string2languagepic($Language);
}
```

[**Picture of the problem**](http://zupimages.net/up/3/292486995.png) *OnSubmit = onClick='this.form.submit()

Comment: just added it :) it's in french normally.

Comment: What have you tried? how do you add that "button click loop" to your html? append?innerHTML?

Comment: It's append, i tried a lot of things but i can't get why my code doesn't keep that value on the submit. 

There are 2 forms : One for the type another for the information.

Comment: The next form is submitted with a normal : submit button 

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>

Comment: You are sure you want to have radio button and not checkbox for CustomerType? if radio you need `checked="checked"`,not just checked.

Comment: Well checked or checked="checked" is not problem here, that's just whether you go strict or transitional. Depending on the Doctype.

But checkboxes is not what i'm looking at, my radio buttons are working well and checked only does his job too. But i just can't keep that value on page reload (on himself) to redirect depending of correct type.

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with that javascript onsubmit because all the other radio buttons keep their default value on page refresh.

Comment: @TreeID you might be right, I tested a form with a radio button that has an onClick event to submit it and it also lost its value, the only way I could get it to work was to add a hidden field and when clicking on the radio button it also added a value to it and then submitted the form, there is probably a better solution.

Comment: Malcolm, your idea seems interesting i'll have a look at it. For the moment i don't see any other solution.

Comment: That was the trick ! Now it's working. thanks Malcolm

Comment: Malcolm don't hesitate to re-post your comment as an answer so i mark it solved.

Comment: @TreeID I have re-posted my comment as an answer :) if I find a better solution I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code a little more I think I have spotted your problem, try the following and see if it works.

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='CustomerType' id='CustomerType' value='$CustomerType' $checked onClick='this.form.submit();' >"
```

If that fails you could always add a hidden field, and when clicking on the radio button it adds a value to it and then submits the form.